# how to make hover:after contents don't push next element

Tags: html, css

I made photo list section

```
<div id="main_post_photo">
          <%
          for(var q=0;q<resolve.length;q++){
              if(resolve[q].images.length>=1){%>
          <a href='/post/<%= resolve[q]._id%>'><img src="../uploads/<%= resolve[q].images[0].images %>" width=150px height=150px></a>
          <%}}%>
</div>
```

when mouse over to image, create rgba(0,0,0,0.3) black cover effect

but when hover occurs, a tag width is two times bigger than before

CSS:

```
#main_post_photo>a:hover:after{
    content: "";
    left:-150px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

how to fix them not to push next contents?

Answer (score 0):

Try `position: absolute;` This way the positioning of the element won't affect other stuff. But you may need to adjust the top probably.

```
#main_post_photo>a:hover:after{
    content: "";
    left:-150px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I solved this problem by transform:translate(-150px,0) and positon:absolute

Comment: You may also want to add `#main_post_photo>a { position:relative }` so the absolute positioning of the `:after` gets based upon that element.